# Codeigniter HMVC Need subfolders like superadmin admin employee

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-hmvc

Codeigniter HMVC I need Folder like this, can anyone please help me?

Superadmin admin and employee have dashboard modules like as follows as More models with same user roles like SuperAdmin, Admin, and Employee.

```
Modules 
Parent Folder - Dashboard
    Superadmin
        controllers models views 
    Admin
        controllers models views
    Employee
        controllers models views`
```

Comment: did you try dashboard/controllers/superadmin/, dashboard/models/superadmin/

Comment: Modified like that structure running url in the page Getting 404 error ... @sintakonte

Comment: which version of hmvc and CI r u using ?

Comment: HMVC version from this https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc              
CI version ..3.1.4 @sintakonte